# More than one GPU on vast.ai

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cloud, gpu

Anyone with experience using vast.ai for cloud GPU computing knows if when renting more than one GPU do you need to do some setup to take advantage of the extra GPUs?

Because I can't notice any difference on speed when renting 6 or 8 GPUs instead of just one. I'm new at using vast.ai for cloud GPU computing.

I am using this default docker:
    Official docker images for deep learning framework TensorFlow   (http://www.tensorflow.org)

> Successfully loaded tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu-py3

And just installing keras afterwards:

```
pip install keras
```

I have also checked the available GPUs using this and all the GPUs are detected correctly:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.tensorflow_backend._get_available_gpus()
```

cheers

Comment: **Update:**

I found about keras.utils.multi_gpu_model, however I keep having this error: 


(AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.config' has no attribute 'experimental_list_devices')

Comment: **Solution:**

I used another docker image with an older version of tensorflow(2.0.0), and the error disapeared, so problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Finally I found the solution myself.  I just used another docker image with an older version of tensorflow (2.0.0), and the error disappeared.